# GCC warning about implicit dereference

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I just ran across the following warning in GCC:

```
warning: implicit dereference will not access object of type ‘volatile util::Yield’ in statement [enabled by default]
```

while compiling this code:

```
volatile util::Yield y1;
util::Yield y2;
y1 += y2; // <--- Warning triggered here.
```

and unfortunately I do not quite understand what GCC is trying to tell me...

The class Yield is declared as follows:

```
class Yield {
public:
    Yield();

    Yield &operator+=(Yield const &other);
    Yield &operator+=(Yield const volatile &other);
    Yield volatile &operator+=(Yield const &other) volatile;
    Yield volatile &operator+=(Yield const volatile &other) volatile;

    // Other operators snipped...
};
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: this warning should be obsolete for c++11 because in c++11 the lvalue of a function call will not be read from anymore.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: It has been a few years, but I still get this warning in C++14 (currently being frustrated by it on GCC latest versions). I wonder if there is some deeper need for it, or if it's just a relic. Recent clang does *not* give such a warning, but doesn't seem like it ever did, looking at old versions in godbolt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the GCC manual, [Section 6.1 - When is a Volatile Object Accessed?](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Volatiles.html)

> *When using a reference to volatile, G++ does not treat equivalent expressions as accesses to volatiles, but instead issues a warning that no volatile is accessed. The rationale for this is that otherwise it becomes difficult to determine where volatile access occur, and not possible to ignore the return value from functions returning volatile references. Again, if you wish to force a read, cast the reference to an rvalue.*

The warning stems from the fact that the += operator returns a *reference* to a volatile object, and that the expression 'y1 += y2' ignores that return value. The compiler is letting you know that the reference will not actually be dereferenced (i.e. the volatile value will not be read).

Comment: And if you don't wish to force a read, how do you write the code to avoid a warning?

Comment: @BenVoigt: `void operator=(Yield const & other) volatile;`

Comment: Having no return value at all is not a good solution. What if it is used in some contexts and not others?