# std::variant converting constructor doesn't handle const volatile qualifiers

Tags: c++, variant, std

The code below:

```
               int i    = 1;
const          int i_c  = 2;
      volatile int i_v  = 3;
const volatile int i_cv = 4;

typedef std::variant<int, const int, volatile int, const volatile int> TVariant;

TVariant var   (i   );
TVariant var_c (i_c );
TVariant var_v (i_v );
TVariant var_cv(i_cv);

std::cerr << std::boolalpha;

std::cerr << std::holds_alternative<               int>(var   ) << std::endl;
std::cerr << std::holds_alternative<const          int>(var_c ) << std::endl;
std::cerr << std::holds_alternative<      volatile int>(var_v ) << std::endl;
std::cerr << std::holds_alternative<const volatile int>(var_cv) << std::endl;

std::cerr << var   .index() << std::endl;
std::cerr << var_c .index() << std::endl;
std::cerr << var_v .index() << std::endl;
std::cerr << var_cv.index() << std::endl;
```

outputs:

```
true
false
false
false
0
0
0
0
```

[coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61344217ae86cb6d)

And so `std::variant` converting constructor doesn't take into account const volatile qualifier of the converting-from type. Is it expected behavior?

Information about converting constructor from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant)

> Constructs a variant holding the alternative type T_j that would be selected by overload resolution for the expression `F(std::forward<T>(t))` if there was an overload of imaginary function F(T_i) for every T_i from Types...

The problem is that in the case above the overload set of such imaginary function is ambiguous:

```
void F(               int) {}
void F(const          int) {}
void F(      volatile int) {}
void F(const volatile int) {}
```

[coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c7e7aece934f1db)

cppreference.com says nothing about this case. Does the standard specify this?

I'm making my own implementation of `std::variant` class. My implementation of converting constructor is based on [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39548402/5447906). And the result is the same as shown above (the first suitable alternative is selected, even though there are others). *libstdc++* probably implements it in the same way, because it also selects the first suitable alternative. But I'm still wondering if this is correct behavior.

Comment: Note that `auto a = var_c` will discard `const`, and `auto b = var_v` will discard `volatile` and this is source of your problems. `int` is always auto deduced when calling constructor.

Comment: @MarekR _Auto deduced_ where? Variant's constructor uses a forwarding reference, where `const` and `volatile` qualifiers are preserved in a template parameter, IIRC ([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iNEvXgMDV8E472bZ)). I believe the problem is with those [imaginary _`FUN`_ functions](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.ctor#12.sentence-2) that pass by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My reading of the standard is that the code should be ill-formed due to ambiguity. It surprises me that both libstdc++ and libc++ appear to allow it.

Here's what [variant.ctor]/12 says:

> Let `T`_j be a type that is determined as follows: build an imaginary function *FUN*(`T`_i) for each alternative type `T`_i. The overload *FUN*(`T`_j) selected by overload resolution for the expression *FUN*`(std::forward<T>(t))` defines the alternative `T`_j which is the type of the contained value after construction.

So four functions are created: initially *FUN*(`int`), *FUN*(`const int`), *FUN*(`volatile int`), and *FUN*(`const volatile int`). These are all equivalent signatures, so they could not be overloaded with each other. This paragraph does not really specify what should happen if the overload set cannot actually be built. However, there is a note that strongly implies a particular interpretation:

> [ *Note:*
>     `variant<string, string> v("abc");`
>   is ill-formed, as both alternative types have an equally viable constructor for the argument. —*end note*]

This note is basically saying that overload resolution cannot distinguish between `string` and `string`. In order for that to happen, overload resolution must be done even though the signatures are the same. The two *FUN*(`string`)s are not collapsed into a single function.

Note that overload resolution is allowed to consider overloads with identical signatures due to templates. For example:

```
template <class T> struct Id1 { using type = T; };
template <class T> struct Id2 { using type = T; };
template <class T> void f(typename Id1<T>::type x);
template <class T> void f(typename Id2<T>::type x);
// ...
f<int>(0);  // ambiguous
```

Here, there are two identical signatures of `f`, and both are submitted to overload resolution but neither is better than the other.

Going back to the Standard's example, it seems that the prescription is to apply the overload resolution procedure even if some of the overloads could not be overloaded with each other as ordinary function declarations. (If you want, imagine that they are all instantiated from templates.) Then, if that overload resolution is ambiguous, the `std::variant` converting constructor call is ill-formed.

The note does not say that the `variant<string, string>` example was ill-formed because the type selected by overload resolution occurs twice in the list of alternatives. It says that the overload resolution itself was ambiguous (because the two types had equally viable constructors). This distinction is important. If this example were rejected *after* the overload resolution stage, an argument could be made that your code is well-formed since the top-level cv-qualifiers would be deleted from the parameter types, making all four overloads *FUN*(`int`) so that `T`_j = `int`. But since the note suggests a failure *during* overload resolution, that means your example is ambiguous (as the 4 signatures are equivalent) and this must be diagnosed.

Comment: This is rejected by trunk gcc and clang.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, this is just how functions work when you pass by value.

The function `void foo(int)` and the function `void foo(const int)` and the function `void foo(volatile int)` and the function `void foo(const volatile int)` [are all *the same function*](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ca09c15b2666f17).

By extension, there is no distinction for your variant's converting constructor to make, and no meaningful way to use a variant whose alternatives differ only in their top-level *cv-qualifier*.

(Well, okay, you can `emplace` with an explicit template argument, as Marek shows, but why? To what end?)

> [`[dcl.fct/5]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5) *[..]* After producing the list of parameter types, any top-level *cv-qualifiers* modifying a parameter type are deleted when forming the function type. *[..]*

Comment: I'm just wondering why the code compiles. Shouldn't it, according to http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.ctor#12.sentence-2, produce some ambiguity error in case there are multiple viable overloads? Is the code well-formed or not? (Kind-of a relevant case is mentioned in this note: http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.ctor#17.note-1, though there are same types).

Comment: @DanielLangr IMO, there are no multiple viable overloads. There is only one converting constructor (after adjustment), possibly multiply-defined (though that's okay for templates). Not really _sure_ whether this is all well-formed though.

Comment: @DanielLangr That note is interesting. Okay maybe it's not well-formed then :P

Comment: Not multiple overloads of the constructor. I meant multiple overloads of those [imaginary _`fun`_ functions](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant.ctor#12.sentence-2) I linked.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you are creating copy of value. This means that `const` and `volatile` modifiers can be safely discarded. That is why template always deduces `int`.

You can force specific type using [emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/emplace).

See demo https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dd054dc4fa9bb9a

Comment: Those warnings are a bit alarming - what do they mean?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869318/gcc-warning-about-implicit-dereference). `emplace` returns the constructed value, and `gcc` warns that discarding that reference to `volatile` return value does not perform a read on it. The warning goes away if you actually do read from the returned reference to `volatile`: https://godbolt.org/z/F24Iea

Comment: @MaxLanghof Got ya.